# CMD - Wait for parallel command lines to finish?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7

I execute 4 tasks in **parallel** via command line ( win7 cmd):

```
start defrag /A c:
start defrag /A d:
start defrag /A e:
start  defrag /A f:
dir
```

However the `dir` command execute right after the first line .

I want the `dir` command to execute after all 4 are done.

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
start defrag /A c:
start defrag /A d:
start defrag /A e:
start defrag /A f:

:StartLoop
:: Check whether any of the defrags are running...
tasklist|Findstr /i /c:"defrag"
:: Exiting the loop if tasklist didn't find any defrags.
If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
   GoTo :ExitLoop
)
choice /T 10 /D Y /M "Waiting for 10 seconds..."
GoTo :StartLoop
:ExitLoop
dir
```

Comment: Thanks how will `%errorlevel%` will get its value ?  ( it is before the choice....)

Comment: _FINDSTR sets %ERRORLEVEL% To 0 (False) if match is found in at least one line of at least one file._ ....thanks. p.s. Im doing it in order to wake up my hard drive after sleep and cause them to spin. defrag /A will run minimal test so it is fine. ( dir /s just reads from fat/ntfs - so this command really make them spin)

Comment: Yep, the `::` is the same as `rem`. Thanks for voting. The %errorlevel% is a environment variable, which tells you how the previous command has performed. If the command was OK, the value is zero, if not the value is not zero. Check [dostips.com](http://www.dostips.com/), it's a great source for DOS scripting.

Answer (score 1):

This will cause `defrag /A [drive]` to run for c, d, e, and f, waiting for each to finish before starting the next. Finally, it will exit and run `dir`.

```
for %%i in (c d e f) do start "" /B /WAIT defrag /A %%i:

dir
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `defrag /M` option to start defrag on multiple drives, and then use the `defrag /T` option to wait for each to complete.  `defrag /T` waits for only a single volume to finish, but since you want to wait for all of them, this will work for you:

```
REM This will start defrag running concurrently on all four drives:
defrag c: d: e: f: /M

REM Wait for each drive to complete.  But since you want to wait of them, that is okay.
REM The order is unimportant
defrag c: /T
defrag d: /T
defrag e: /T
defrag f: /T

REM They are all done.  You are set to whatever you want to do next.
dir
```